# How can I use switch between different environments using the new cypress.config.js in Cypress 10x?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, configuration-files

I used to have json files under my `config` folder containing variables for different environments. For example:
`local.env.json` would contain:

```json
{
"baseUrl": "localhost:8080"
}
```

then another one called `uat.env.json` would contain:

```json
{
"baseUrl": "https://uat.test.com"
}
```

and its configured on my `plugins/index.ts` as:

```js
    const version = config.env.version || 'uat'; // if version is not defined, default to this stable environment
    config.env = require(`../../config/${version}.env.json`);  // load env from json
```

I will then call it on my tests with `cy.visit(Cypress.env().baseUrl))` then pass it on the CI with `CYPRESS_VERSION=uat npx cypress run`

However, with the new Cypress 10x version, the plugin file has been deprecated and just relies on `cypress.config.js`. I can't find any example on their documentation on how this can be done (I remember they used to have a page with these scenarios but can't find it now).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use the old `plugins/index.ts` in the new `cypress.config.ts` by importing it.

This is the simplest example (with no new config in `cypress.config.ts`)

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import legacyConfig from './cypress/plugins/index.js'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return legacyConfig(on, config)  // call legacy config fn and return result
    }
  }
})
```

The typescript and modules may cause you grief about typings etc. I've not tried it in a typescript project, but it does work in a javascript project.

Alternatively, copy/paste everything from `plugins/index.ts` instead of calling the legacy function. This might be better as you add more plugins in the future.

Comment: Thanks and I upvoted the answer. I forgot to mention though that I'd like my env variables on the `cypress.config.js` too with something like below:
`
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config);
        },
        specPattern: 'cypress/tests/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
        env: {
            local: {
                baseUrl: 'localhost:8080',
            },
            uat: {
                baseUrl: 'https://uat.test.com',
            }
        },
    },
`

Comment: It's a different question, you want to know how to change the `require(`../../config/${version}.env.json`)` to picking one from the `env` object. Should be fairly straight forward, but unless you *never* have any other `env` vars (say for a plugin), then you should add them all under another property like `env: { versions: { local: [...}, uat: {...} }}`.